# How do you overload operator+ in a subclass of an abstract superclass?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, operator-overloading, enumerator

So I am doing some tinkering with inheritance and abstract classes. In the instance I am programming I have created an array of pointers to Shape, my abstract base class. After filling the first 2 spots in the array with Square subclass pointers, I fill the third with the sum of the previous two. This gives me an "expression must have integral or unscoped enum type" error, which is giving me some trouble. Additionally, it gives me the error "'+' cannot add two pointers."

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include "Shape.h"
#include "Square.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Shape** shapes = new Shape*[3];
    shapes[0] = new Square(12);
    shapes[1] = new Square(4);
    shapes[2] = shapes[0] + shapes[1];

    delete[] shapes;
    return 0;
}
```

Interestingly enough, if I set the third index equal to the second index it works fine.

Here are my Square operators below.

```
Square& Square::operator=(const Square& c1)
{
    if (this != &c1)
    {
        this->length_O = c1.GetLength();
        this->width_O = c1.GetWidth();
    }
    return *this;
}

Square& Square::operator+=(const Square& c1)
{
    if (this != &c1)
    {
        this->length_O = c1.GetLength();
        this->width_O = c1.GetWidth();
    }
    return *this;
}

const Square Square::operator+(const Square& c1) const
{
    return Square(*this) += c1;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `if (this != &c1)` -- Why is this test in `operator+=`?  This `a += a;` should be perfectly valid.

Comment: *Additionally, it gives me the error "'+' cannot add two pointers."* -- Explain what this line does: `shapes[2] = shapes[0] + shapes[1];`

Comment: It looks like your `operator+=` is exactly the same as your `operator=`. Is that intended?

Answer (score 0):

Unable to try compiling your code since the class definitions were not available.
At a glance, this line of code does not look correct.

```
shapes[2] = shapes[0] + shapes[1];
```

`shapes[2]` is a pointer to shape, but you have not created an instance of `shape` for that index off of the heap yet.  So something like this may fix your issue, however once again I was not able to test this since the class definitions were not available in the original post

```
shapes[2] = new Square();
*shapes[2] = *shapes[0] + *shapes[1];
```

In regards to your implementation working when you simply set the third index equal to the second index; that probably works because it sounds like you are setting your third index to point to the same address that your second index is pointing to.  If so, that is valid since they are just addresses